# dyld: Symbol not found: __TMPdCSs12AnyGenerator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

[image]

when I try to build and Run my project it gives me an error of `symbol not found: __TMPdCSs12AnyGenerator`

I had installed Xcode 7 beta on my system. When I installed it gives me an error of **realm module not found** so I just removed realm framework and added again after adding this frameworks again it gives about stated error.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Swift was this RealmSwift framework built with? Can you rebuild the framework?

Comment: its  for 2.1.1 version of swift.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem after I update my XCode from 7.2 to 7.3. I use a framework build from XCode7.2. After I rebuild the framework on XCode7.3, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.framework` to the “Embedded Binaries” section of your Xcode target.

You can check, if you have followed these steps correctly by following these steps:

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator.
2. Select your application target in the side bar in the section "Targets".
3. Navigate to the tab "Build Phases"
4. Expand the phase "Embed Frameworks"
5. The destination should equal "Frameworks". The list should contain `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.framework`.

If such phase doesn't exist, please create a Copy Files phase by clicking on the plus in the upper left corner and selecting "New Copy Files Phase". Select as destination "Frameworks" and add the `Realm.framework` and the `ReamSwift.framework` there.

I've added two exemplary screenshots below, so you can compare graphically how it should look like.

#### General Tab

[image: General Tab]

#### Build Phases Tab

[image: Build Phases]

#### Application Bundle in the Built Products Directory

[image: Application Bundle]

Comment: Could you check then please whether `RealmSwift.framework` exists in your application bundles `Framworks` directory within the built products directory? If not, it would help if you could post a screenshot of the "Build Phases" tab from your Xcode target, where you expanded the pane "Embed Frameworks"?

Comment: I added the build phases screenshot @marius and what i think i am using Xcode beta in that swift 3 is there and the framework which I added is for swift 2.1.1.

Comment: Did you tried to clean your build folder and rebuild?

Comment: it works on lower version of swift but on swift 3 it gives me crash

Comment: Oh okay, totally missed that in your previous comment. We don't support that yet with our prebuilt binaries. You could try though to integrate it via CocoaPods / or just build it yourself separately.

Comment: Please see also [issue #3287 on our repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3287). You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

there's an update released for these frameworks to support Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3):

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v0.98.6