# iOS app rejected by Apple because of Realm Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm, dyld

Using XCode 7.3, my app will not run on any device that is not run in Xcode. So I tried using Fabric and Crashlytics and I get no error messages back but the app will not run (crashes on launch)

I tried submitting to TestFlight and Apple rejected it saying this was the error when they ran it:

```
    Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Symbol not found: __TMPdCSs12AnyGenerator
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/806A5CCE-1852-4EDB-8534-07F267576A61/Art For Life.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
  Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/806A5CCE-1852-4EDB-8534-07F267576A61/Art For Life.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/806A5CCE-1852-4EDB-8534-07F267576A61/Art For Life.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
  Dyld Version: 390.7
```

I've tried this [dyld: Symbol not found: __TMPdCSs12AnyGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789155/dyld-symbol-not-found-tmpdcss12anygenerator). But it did not work.

I'm pretty new to iOS development so not sure if it something with frameworks or where they are, how they are organized, etc.

Comment: That's odd. Following those steps in that other thread should fix it. At this point, it's probably best to completely remove Realm from your project and then try re-installing it again.

Comment: @TiM It's weird because it worked fine before outside of xCode a couple weeks ago. I did recently use the RealmSearchViewController and that was when it stopped working (crashing with TestFairy, TestFlight etc).