# Dynamic framework dyld: Symbol not found:

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I created a framework with Swift and uses cocoapods for the third party dependecies. When I send this .framework to our a developer to use in another project (also uses cocoapods) he is getting the following error in runtime.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TFC10RealmSwift6Object20addNotificationBlockfFOS_12ObjectChangeT_CSo20RLMNotificationToken
 Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB31A431-EBB0-484E-ABB4-844292B23588/libraryapplication.app/Frameworks/XXXSDK.framework/XXXSDK
 Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB31A431-EBB0-484E-ABB4-844292B23588/libraryapplication.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB31A431-EBB0-484E-ABB4-844292B23588/libraryapplication.app/Frameworks/XXXSDK.framework/XXXSDK
```

any idea or how we can fix that?

Comment: Did you try to clean project and build again?

Comment: Yes, we've been with this issue for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem was I was building the framework in Debug mode instead of Release. After changing that it works perfectly.

Comment: crash happens to when building in release mode as well. Not sure if this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the framework in the "Embedded Binaries" section of your target, and not only in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"

This is usually what causes issues with external frameworks in swift:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure he does. I think is something related with cocoapods and the generation of the framework, but don't know what.

Comment: When you don't add to embedded binaries, the error is something like image not found, this is not the case.

Comment: I believe this is what you are experiencing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789155/dyld-symbol-not-found-tmpdcss12anygenerator

Comment: Yes but can find a proper solution :(

Comment: maybe the real framework is not included / used in your own framework? because it says its used in your SDK, and expected to be in realm, did you check your framework includes also? can you post them? and some kind of usage you have with the realm framework?